# C# - how can I get owner's name for a Mutex

Tags: c#, synchronization, mutex

I have a shared mutex between 2 applications.
I want to create an administration console that shows the current owner's name of the mutex.

How can I get the application name that currently owns the Mutex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible at the user mode level.  You will have to install a driver or kernel plugin in order to get this information.

It's almost the same question as asking "what process opened this file"?

Comment: I see...
With Process Explorer, I see the files an executable is holding.
Is it possible to know if a known executable is holding a known Mutex ?

Comment: It's because process explorer is inserting kernel level drivers under the hood.  That's why it doesn't work with this feature in normal user mode.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this issue but I'm reasonably confident