# How to get PIDs that are using given file name in C#?

Tags: c#, file, winapi, mutex, handle

How to get PIDs of processes that are using a given file name and mutex name?
(Not by custom kernel driver, but in C# in user mode.)

**UPDATE**: Thanks to Daniel Renshaw I found [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947312/win32-how-to-get-the-process-thread-that-owns-a-mutex/1948105#1948105) that lists all handles with PIDs. (Using a not undocumented and unfrozen functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two SO questions may be of use:

[How do I find out which process is locking a file using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net)

Summary: use [handle.exe](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsysinternals%2Fbb896655.aspx&ei=H7AQTKjwD6KO4gaFppiICA&usg=AFQjCNFRlOEv1IIrPW_3LOy3-pBySWwfyQ) and parse the output (i.e. not a great solution)

[Win32: How to get the process/thread that owns a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947312/win32-how-to-get-the-process-thread-that-owns-a-mutex)

Summary: may not be possible in user mode without using deprecated or undocumented functions (but some smaple code is provided in this question).

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but `handle.exe` does not seem to work well. I was trying running from a cmd `handle C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. It says: `No matching handles found.` (I am using latest version.) And also does not seem to work for mutexes.

How to make the script in the second post to print the handle names?