# Find and Close all Application Instances using Mutex (Inno Setup)

Tags: inno-setup

My application has a specific Mutex. I want Inno Setup to find and close all application instances using the Mutex before Install and Uninstall.

I have already tried (with no success):

```
[Setup]
AppMutex={#MyMutex}
```

It doesn't close, it only warns the user "application is currently running".

```
[Setup]
CloseApplications=force
```

It can only close if the running application filename equals the install filename.

Comment: I think the built in features can only help you this far. Write some Pascal Script and you should be able to easily implement what you wanted.

Comment: Mutex is not the right tool to find applications. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/541477/850848. + Mutex can be held by a single application only, that's why it is mutex (mutually exclusive). So *"**all** applications"* does not make sense in this context.